# How to map a value to a fuzzy term in python

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

Following the [tip example](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html#example-plot-tipping-problem-newapi-py) from [scikit-fuzzy](https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/), I have used the following code to create an input/output to a fuzzy control system:

```
quality = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'quality')
service = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'service')
tip = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 26, 1), 'tip')
quality.automf(3)
service.automf(3)
tip.automf(3)
```

In the "Fuzzy rules" section of the example, the rules are manually written. I would like to generate them from training examples.

Suppose I have a set of (*quality*, *service*, *tip*) tuples, where *quality* and *service* range from 0 to 10 and *tip* ranges from 0 to 25. I would like to be able to generate automatically a rule from each training tuple. In order to do so, I need to map the values of *quality* and *service* (respectively *tip*) to a term (a.k.a linguistic value): either 'poor', 'average', or 'good' (respectively 'low', 'medium', or 'high').

How can I do that with `scikit-fuzzy` ?

Answer (score 5):

The function I need is `skfuzzy.interp_membership`: if I want to have the fuzzy term/linguistic value for the crisp value 4.0, I evaluate each membership function at 4.0:

```
skfuzzy.interp_membership(np.arange(0, 11, 1), quality['poor'].mf, 4.0)
skfuzzy.interp_membership(np.arange(0, 11, 1), quality['average'].mf, 4.0)
skfuzzy.interp_membership(np.arange(0, 11, 1), quality['good'].mf, 4.0)
```

and then the fuzzy value would be the one for which the membership function has the maximum value